# How to write and read from a named pipe in C?

Tags: c, named-pipes

I have 2 programs (write.c and read.c). I want to continuously write to the named pipe from standard input, and read from it on the other end (and write to standard output). I've made something work, but it isn't working right. The program on the other end reads in the wrong order or reads special characters (so it reads more then it needs?). I also want to be able to compare the named pipe output to a certain string.

Anyways, here's the code from both files:

**write.c:**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 512
#define err(mess) { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); }

void main()
{
    int fd, n;

    char buf[BUFFSIZE];


    mkfifo("fifo_x", 0666);
    if ( (fd = open("fifo_x", O_WRONLY)) < 0)
        err("open")

    while( (n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFSIZE) ) > 0) {
        if ( write(fd, buf, strlen(buf)) != strlen(buf)) { 
            err("write");
        }
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

**read.c:**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 512
#define err(mess) { fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s.", mess); exit(1); }

void main()
{
    int fd, n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];

    if ( (fd = open("fifo_x", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        err("open")


    while( (n = read(fd, buf, BUFFSIZE) ) > 0) {

        if ( write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n) { 
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

**Example of input:**

```
hello how are you
123 
test
```

**Example of incorrect output:**

```
hello how are you
b123
o how are you
btest
 how are you
b
```

**Another example of input:**

```
test
hi
```

**And output:**

```
test
hi
t
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The buffer modify by read is not a valid c string so

```
write(fd, buf, strlen(buf)) != strlen(buf) // write.c
```

is undefined behaviour. You should do

```
write(fd, buf, n) != n
```

because you read n octet with `read()`.

It's funny because you do it for read.c but not for write.c

---

The type of `n` must but `ssize_t` and not `int`, [man read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read).

---

`main()` must return a `int` [Declare main prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020362/declare-main-prototype)

Comment: Wow, I actually had it correct at first, but changed it for god know what reason.. Thanks.