# Printf on data stored as union gives no output after called for double variable

Tags: c, unions

I'm working on program which input looks as follows:

3.14 (it's variable stored in union)
4 (number of calls)
int (asked types to return)
long
float
double

On output should i get:
1078523331
1078523331
3.140000
0.000000

[Full instruction to this task](http://www.staff.amu.edu.pl/~przemeks/files/ppr30.txt)
My program works except on double case: instead of giving me any output program gives me none. Can anyone explain me why? Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 1000
#define CHARLENGTH 6
union Data {
  int i;
  long long l;
  float f;
  double d;
};
int main(){
  union Data x;
  char types[SIZE][CHARLENGTH];
  int n;
  scanf("%f",&x.f);
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(int i = 0;i<=n+1;i++){
    fgets(types[i],CHARLENGTH,stdin);
    types[i][strcspn(types[i],"\n")] ='\0';//removing newline
  }

  for(int i = 1;i<=n+1;i++){
    if(strcmp(types[i], "int") == 0){
      printf("%d\n",x.i);
    }
    else if(strcmp(types[i], "long") == 0){
      printf("%lli\n",x.l);
    }
    else if(strcmp(types[i], "float") == 0){
      printf("%f\n",x.f);
    }
    else if(strcmp(types[i], "double") == 0){
      printf("%lf\n",x.d);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `x.d` is uninitialized, and so to try and read it will invoke [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You could change `union Data x;` to something like `union Data x = { 1078523331, 1078523331, 3.20f, 0.0 };`

Comment: Not exactly, @George.  It is true the `x` is not initialized, but a value is assigned to it via the first `scanf()`.  And if it *were* initialized, one would ordinarily provide only one initializer element, since it's a *union*.  There is a fine point here: supposing that `sizeof(double) > sizeof(float)`, setting the value of `x.f` results in *unspecified* values for some of the bytes of `x.d`.  But that's a different situation from an unintialized object having an *indeterminate* value.  Use of the later produces UB, but use of the former does not necessarily do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not allow sufficient space in array `types` for a six-character string such as `"double"`, because you need an extra byte for the terminator.  Because you have used `fgets()` in a reasonable way, however, you have saved yourself from overrunning the bounds of that array -- `fgets()` just stops reading after the fifth character of "double", and appends a terminator.  Therefore, what actually gets stored is `"doubl"`.  Naturally, that compares different from `"double"`, so no corresponding output is produced.

- In the first place, you should increase `CHARLENGTH` to at least 7.  Doing so will take care of your immediate problem.
- You should also consider adding a final `else` clause inside your loop that prints out a diagnostic message in the event that none of the other cases is satisfied.  Such a message could have clued you in to what's going on.
- for robustness, you might consider making sure to read and discard any trailing junk on the `type` lines; as it is, even trailing whitespace after one of the shorter type names will screw up your matching.
- Perhaps it's respondent to the exercise as it is, but your program would be a lot more user friendly if it prompted for each input item.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Three</strike> Four quick observations:

0) As a minimum, the `main` function should be: *[int main(void)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020691/645128)*.

1) Because  C strings are defined as an array of `char` terminated with NULL, the string "double" requires a buffer with space for 7 `char` to contain it.

```
|d|o|u|b|l|e|\0|    //includes NULL char termination
```

Change

```
#define CHARLENGTH 6
```

to

```
#define CHARLENGTH 7
```

2) Because it is not clear from the cmd line prompts in the running program what items are to be entered, if one of the string `types`, eg "double", is not entered, the line:

```
fgets(types[i],CHARLENGTH,stdin);
```

will not do as it is intended.  Suggest adding some `printf` statements with instructions for what to enter for all 3 entries per line.

3) `types` is not initialized before use.
This can be addressed by simply initializing like this:

```
memset(types, 0, SIZE*CHARLENGTH);
```

or even simpler:

```
char types[SIZE][CHARLENGTH] = {0};
```

A comparison of what the memory looks like by the time it gets to the `fgets` statement, uninitialized, or initialized (by either method): 
[image: ![enter image description here]