# why in this program runtime error depend on value of input?

Tags: c, runtime, runtime-error, dynamic-memory-allocation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU6lD.png

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main() 
{
    int i,n,*a=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int)); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) 
    scanf("%d",(a+i)); 
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) 
    printf("%d",*(a+i));
    free(a); 
    return 0; 
}
```

the above program run smootly till input(i.e. n) is less than or equal to 6.If I input n greater than 6 then it is showing runtime error.WHY?here runtime error depends on value of input??)

Comment: You are using the value of an uninitialized variable `n` to allocate memory. that `malloc()` need to be put **after** `scanf()`.

Comment: And I suggest you put the code inside your question, instead of uploading it as an image. There is a code tag for it in SO which works perfectly fine for c code.

Answer (score 0):

try this at top:

```
int i = 0;
int n = 0;
int *a = NULL;
scanf("%d", &n);
if(n > 0) {
    a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(!a) {
        printf("malloc failed");
        return 0;
    }
}
else {
    printf("enter number > 0");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO. Your program invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB) when you do `malloc(n * sizeof(int))` because the variable `n` is not initialized and reading / using an uninitialized variable results in UB.

What do you think the value of `n` will be when you call `malloc`? `n` might even be a negative value. Once you invoke UB, there is no telling what your program will do. You should put your call to `scanf` before you call `malloc`.

Your `main` function is *not* standards complaint. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020362/declare-main-prototype) From next time please put your code directly in the question.

Comment: It is. ____________

Comment: @PeterJ What do you mean?

Comment: @PeterJ You think `int main()` is standards complaint?