# Is int main(void) { } a prototype?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand declarations, definitions and prototypes.  I came across the excellent post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41805712/1825603.  I do, however, need some clarification, but because I do not have enough reputation to comment directly to the post, I will ask here...

The relevant section:

> In definitions
>
> `void func1() { }     // obsolescent`
>
> and
>
> `void func2(void) { }`
>
> The former declares and defines a function func1
> that has no parameters and no prototype
>
> The latter declares and defines a function func2 with a prototype that
> has no parameters.

When I see `int main(void) { }` as one of the Standard definitions for main in C99 5.1.2.2.1, I interpret from the above that it's "a declaration and definition of a function with a prototype that has no parameters".  My confusion lies with C99 5.1.2.2.1, where it says, "The implementation declares no prototype for this function."  By adding the `void` to `int main() { }`, does this mean the user-level code is declaring a prototype because the implementation hasn't?  And if it's not a prototype, what is the effect of adding `void`?

Note: I believe I understand the reason the declaration `int main(void);` isn't used, ie, [Declare main prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020362/declare-main-prototype), but don't think my question is a duplicate of this.

Comment: In C when you declare a function without any arguments, you can actually call it with an arbitrary number of arguments. For example `int a() { return 1;}` can be called as `a()` or `a(1,1,1)`. If you add `void` as the argument, then the compiler will complain if you pass any argument. With `int a(void) { return 1;}` you can only call `a()` but `a(1,1,1)` is not possible anymore.

Comment: The `main` function is quite special, because it has multiple valid prototypes. `int main(int argc, char **argv)` is one, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is another, but `int main(void)` is another. In the last case, I'd say it's more a hint for the programmer that the program does not take any command line arguments. My guess is that by using `void` the compiler might optimize the start of the program and not allocate any memory for the command line arguments, even when they are passed. This is only my speculation, I don't really know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C 2018 6.2.1 2 says:

> … ((A *function prototype* is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.)

Thus `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);` is a function prototype, because it declares the types of its parameters, `argc` and `argv`.

`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {}` is also a function prototype. Even thought it is a function definition, it also declares the function.

Functions can be defined with an old style that did not have declarations in the parameter list, such as:

```
int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
}
```

Although the types of the parameters are declared in the declaration list between the function declarator and the body of the function, this is not what the C standard means by declaring the types of the parameters. This phrasing in the C standard is unfortunately imprecise, but the intent is that a “function prototype” is a declaration of the modern form with the types specified in the parameter list, contrasted with the legacy form with only the parameter names in the list.

We can see this because C 2018 6.2.7 3 distinguishes a function prototype as a function declared with a parameter type list rather than a simple identifier list:

> … a function type with a parameter type list (a function prototype)…

Also note the special form `(void)`, as in `int foo(void)`, counts as a function prototype as a special case; it is the modern form of declaration that asserts the function has no parameters. The old form `int foo();` does not specify whether the function has parameters or not.

Comment: I've recently discovered gcc's -Wstrict-prototypes warning option, and it has been helpful while learning this stuff.  Combined with -pedantic-errors and -Wimplicit-int, it's easy to see the differences between the old and new ways of declaring/defining functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `int main(void) { }` a prototype?

Yes.

`int main(void) { }` is a function *declaration* and *definition*.  As a *declaration*, it says nothing about the parameters.  As a *definition*, it takes no parameters: i.e `void`.